# how to add checkbox in each row of listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, contacts

I am using listview to get the phone contacts from this link.
 http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-contacts-content-provider-retrieving-and-listing-contacts-in-listview-example/  .now i want to insert multichoice checkboxes in each row of listview. Can anyone help me with this scenario?

Comment: http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/04/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Answer (score 0):

U have to use custom adapter class and layout file
"http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

---

"

Comment: these tutorial are sample of adding checkbox. i want which one is related to my application